# why heaxadecimal numbers are prefixed with "0* "

Tags: binary, hex, decimal

Instead of writing ffff why the syntax of writing heaxadecimal number's are like 0*ffff.What is the meaning of "0*". Does it specify something?
Anyhow A,B,C,D,E,F notations only in hexa decimal number system. Then whats the need of "0*".

Sorry "*" was not  the character i supposed it is "x" .
Is it a nomenclature or notation for hexadecimal number systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typically 0**x**FFFF: the letter, not the multiplication symbol.

As for *why*, `0x` is just the most common convention, like how some programming languages allow binary to be prefixed by `0b`. Prefixing a number with just 0 is typically reserved for octal, or base 8; they wanted a way to tell the machine that the following number is in hexadecimal, or base 16 (`10` != `0b10` [2] != `010` [8] != `0x10` [16]). They typically omitted a small 'o' from identifying octal for human readability purposes.

Interestingly enough, most Assembly-based implementations I've come across use (or at least allow the use of) `0h` instead or as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what language you are talking about, but if you for example in C# write

```
var ffffff = "Some unrelated string";
...
var nowYouveDoneIt = ffffff;
```

what do you expect to happen? How does the compiler know if ffffff refers to the hexadecimal representation of the decimal number 16777215 or to the string variable defined earlier?

Since identifiers (in C#) can't begin with a number, prefixing with a 0 and some other character (in C# it's 0xffffff or hex and 0b111111111111111111111111 for binary IIRC) is a handy way of communicating what base the number literal is in.

EDIT: Another issue, if you were to write `var myCoolNumber = 10`, how would you have ANY way of knowing if this means 2, 10 or 16? Or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It's there to indicate the number as heX. It's not '*', it's 'x' actually.

See:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_constants.htm